# Issues creating a custom netinstall image

Tags: macos

Recently I had great success in creating a netinstall image of mac os x high sierra. I was able to generate the nbi file via system image utility. Was able to test run it on some of the mac os machines. Runs like a charm. Here's the problem that I'm currently facing. I'm trying to construct a custom netinstall image. I've wrote a shell script, that will act as the post installation script. I've tried numerous attempts to try creating the custom install via system image utility and I'm hit with the infamous system image utility error 2 message. Any suggestions or ideas? Also does anyone know where system image utility stores its log files. I've been unable to trace it in the /var/log directory. Thanks!

Comment: I think @GordonDavisson literally wrote the book on this. If anyone around here knows, it's probably him.